# Can we run Spring Batch multiple times a day?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have implemented Spring batch before couple of times before but it was designed to run only once in a day.

Now I have a new requirement where I need to start the batch whenever a record gets inserted into the table. whenver a new record is inserted, it will launch the job and batch will generate PDF and save it in repository and send mail to user.

I am not sure how to design a spring batch which runs multiple times a day or is it even correct to go for Spring batch for this scenario. Can someone please throw some light on this. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a listener to catch when data are stored in db (easily with hibernate for instance) and then use `CommandLineJobRunner` to start your job manually.

See [spring_source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html)

You can run it several times, just be careful with identifier pattern use for your batch instance

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference !!!
I am reviewing it and will let you know if I have further questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, you can achieve this with the help of @EntityListeners (if working hiberante).
let me give you dummy scenario :-

```
 @Entity
  @Table(name="Order")
  @EntityListeners(OrderListner.class)
  public class Order{

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    // other properties
  }
```

This Listener :-

```
class OrderListner{

    @PostPersist
    public void doStartSchedulerCode(){
        // You can call the code from here responobile for generating pdf and send mail,

    }

  }
```

Each time you will insert a row in order table,doStartSchedulerCode() will be called.
Try this

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference !!!
I am implementing this code in my local and will let you know if I have any questions :)

Comment: @Saimuga did u try this

Comment: Hi Sachin, 
Sorry for the late reply. Yes I have tried the entity listener and it works as expected with Oracle database. However Our requirement changed to running the batch job once at night. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge :)